# Obscure passage in the calculus of a limit

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Here is the multivariable limit with $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)\\(x,y)\neq(0,0)} \frac{1-\cos(x^{3}y^{2\lambda})}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2\lambda+1}}$$

I'm studying 2 different cases: $\lambda\ge0$ and $\lambda < 0$.

Let $\lambda$ be strictly negative:  $(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2\lambda+1}$ is evaluated to a negative power if $\lambda < -\frac{1}{2}$. So the limit is equal to $0$.

But how can I study the subcase $-\frac{1}{2}\le\lambda<0$? If I exclude the the direction $y=0$ (x-axis) I find that the limit exist and is equal to zero but how about the x-axis? The limit doesn't exist? Or the domain is not defined in $y=0$ for $-\frac{1}{2}\le\lambda<0$? I don't understand this conceptual passage. Thanks in advice!

Comment: If you plug in the equivalent of the numerator what do you get?

Comment: @Sebastiano :) my fault. I don't understand, of course!!

Comment: @GiacomoGatti I have deleted an useful comment....and my re-welcome :-)

Comment: Expand cos in a McLaurin series and then switch to polar coordinates.

Comment: @blamethelag yes, I've used this asymptotic for the other cases but if $-\frac{1}{2}\le\lambda<0$ the argument of cos is not defined at all and I can't use this transformation. maybe I'm wrong

Comment: @Matematleta yes I've switched to polar coordinates but my question is still alive. The argument of the cos is not defined for $-\frac{1}{2}\le\lambda<0$ (also for $\lambda<-\frac{1}{2}$ but in this case the denominator have a negative power so the entire limit tend to zero independently of cos). Maybe I don't understand this specific point and that's why I'm struggling

Comment: Ok I think I understand your question. In the case $-1/2 < \lambda < 0$ you can try to plug in $x = x_n$, $y = y_n$ that goes to $0$ and see what happends if you allow $x_n$ to go faster to $0$ than $y_n$ and the contrary. Here obviously you want to try powers of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $-1/2<\lambda<0.$ Then, $ \frac{1-\cos(x^{3}y^{2\lambda})}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2\lambda+1}}=\frac{1-(\cos (r^{3+2\lambda}f(\theta)))}{r^{4\lambda +2}}$ where $|f(\theta)|\le 1.$ Expand the numerator in a power series to see that the absolute value of the foregoing expression is less than $r^{1-2\lambda}+\frac{O(r^{3+2\lambda})}{r^{4\lambda +2}}\to 0.$

If $\lambda =-1/2,$ we have $1-\cos(x^{3}y^{-1}).$ If $x=y$ the imit is zero. If $x^3=y$ the limit is $1-\cos 1\neq 0$ so the limit does not exist.

Comment: Now it's clear, Thank you :):):)

Comment: You're welcome. But see my edit!